# Powershell Post API Request

Tags: rest, api, powershell, post

I'm able to post the request using bash with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
APIKey="apikeyhere"
content="{\"accessToken\":\"$APIKey\",\"elements\":[{\"serialnumber\":\"AAAAAAAAA\",\"name\":\"EXAMPLENAME\",\"tags\":\"EXAMPLETAG\"}]}"
curl  -s -k -X POST -d 'content='$content 'https://apiaccess.example.com/v2/devices'
```

I tried to use powershell but get an error "INVALID REQUEST":

```
$body = @{
"accessToken"="APIKeyhere"
"elements" = @{
 "serialnumber"="AAAAA"
 "name"="DeviceName"
 "tags"="tag1,tag2"
}} | ConvertTo-Json

$header = @{
 "Accept"="application/json"
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
} 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://apiaccess.example.com/v2/devices" -Method 'Post' -Body $body -Headers $header | ConvertTo-HTML
```

Any pointed regarding how I can fix the powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this: `| ConvertTo-Json`

Your headers can be replaced with this: `-ContentType application/json`

You should probably not convert the results to HTML until you've experimented with the data you get back. But that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once and had to translate a CURL request into Powershell. Maybe the following article will help you:
[CURL to Powershell example](https://techblog.jere.ch/2019/02/25/get-data-from-bluecat-dns-server-with-rest-api/)

i got also the Error

> "INVALID REQUEST":...

In my case, the API was weird. CURL made a simple fallback of a GET request to the POST method... it took hours to realize that I had to do a POST instead of a GET in Powershell.